# VSCode auto-complete extension that looks at all open files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently switched to VSCode and looking for an extension that will look at all open files when suggesting auto-completions. For example, say I have an HTML doc and a JavaScript file open. As I'm typing in JavaScript I'd like auto-complete suggestions from, say, the id values in the HTML tags.
I've done some searching in the marketplace, but haven't found anything. Anyone know if it exists?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atishay-Jain.All-Autocomplete.

I actually never tried :D

Comment: just tried it, works great, thanks